# Integration Service cannot be upgraded/removed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, installation

I have SQL Server 2005 Integration Services installed in our server whose version is 5292. It needs to be upgraded to version 5324. After running the patch the summary report says it is upgraded successfully. But the version is still 5292 when I connect with SSMS. For compliance purposes, I tried to remove it, but that failed unfortunately. The report says the server is lacking the IIS component. That put me in a quandary.

Now I think removing the service might be easier than upgrading it.

Have you encountered anything similar? How can I force removal of Integration Services?